Is there a definition of meromorphic maps between two Riemann surfaces?
Is there a notion of a "meromorphic map" between two arbitrary Riemann surfaces, $X$ and $Y$?
In the first section Otto Forster's book on Riemann surfaces, he gives a definition of a "holomorphic function" $X\to\mathbb{C}$ for a Riemann surface $X$. He then generalizes this definition to "holomorphic mappings" $X\to Y$ between any two Riemann surfaces.
Later in that section, he defines a "meromorphic function". The obvious question to me is then whether we can generalize this to a definition of "meromorphic mapping" between two arbitrary Riemann surfaces.
The obvious approach would be to define it to be a mapping which is meromorphic in charts. Specifically this would mean that a meromorphic mapping from $X$ to $Y$ is a holomorphic mapping $f:X'\to Y$ where $X'$ is an open subset of $X$ such that $X\setminus X'$ contains only isolated points, and for every pair of charts $\psi_1:U_1\to V_1$ on $X$ and $\psi_2:U_2\to V_2$ on $Y$ with $f(U_1\cap X')\subseteq U_2$, the mapping $\psi_2\circ f\circ\psi_1^{-1}$ is a meromorphic function in the usual sense.
The issue is that I am not sure if the above definition gives us something reasonable. Does anyone know?
Edit: I wanted to add another thought I had. In the case of $Y=\mathbb{C}$, there is an isomorphism between meromorphic functions on $X$, and holomorphic mappings $X\to\mathbb{P}_\mathbb{C}^1$ which do not equal the constant function $\infty$. So a notion of "meromorphic mapping" should probably have this isomorphism too. Specifically, this means that for any compact Riemann surface $Y$ and any $p\in Y$, meromorphic mappings $X\to Y\setminus\{p\}$ should be equivalent to holomorphic mappings $X\to Y$ which do not equal the constant function $p$. I do not know if the definition I gave above satisfies this equivalence.

Although it's hard to be definitive about saying "no" to a qualitative question, existing (widespread) usage of meromorphic entails taking values in $\mathbf{CP}^{1}$. "Meromorphic in charts" means "locally holomorphic to the projective line," which patches globally to the usual definition.

@AndrewD.Hwang I see, so there is no common usage of "meromorphic" with a more general codomain like there is for "holomorphic". I don't fully understand you argument about "meromorphic in charts". Are you saying that the definition of "meromorphic mapping" I gave above forces $Y=\mathbb{C}$?

Right; between friends, "meromorphic" means "locally a quotient of holomorphic functions $f/g$," i.e., a mapping to the projective line via $[f/g:1] = [f:g]$ or $[1:f/g] = [g:f]$. <> The point about patching is, if a mapping (which by definition has a fixed codomain) locally takes values in the projective line, then the codomain is the projective line.

@AndrewD.Hwang I don’t think what you’re saying is right. For example, let $X$ be a complex torus and let $f:X\to X$ be the identity function. Then $f$ is a homomorphic mapping and therefore also a meromorphic mapping under the definition I gave. But it’s codomain is not the projective line even though it locally takes values in the projective line.

One is certainly free to introduce a new definition of meromorphic in a way that every holomorphic map is "meromorphic." The point of my comments is just that if the new definition does not extend "locally a quotient of holomorphic functions," I think the new definition is liable to mislead. <> The identity map of a torus is not "locally a quotient of holomorphic functions" in the sense of my previous comment. Can you clarify the sense in which this map "locally takes values in the projective line"? Are you thinking of a coordinate chart on the codomain torus...?

@AndrewD.Hwang True, but it is still "locally a quotient of holomorphic functions" in charts. And yes, the proposed definition of "meromorphic mapping" I gave in my question included using a coordinate chart on the codomain, and thus, one can say that it "locally takes takes values in the projective line".

Let's start over: There is a widely-used definition of meromorphic function. On a curve (Riemann surface) this amounts to a holomorphic mapping to the projective line (via my second comment above). Generally, meromorphy involves global sections of a particular sheaf, which are "locally quotients of holomorphic functions" in the sense of being quotients of global sections of some holomorphic line bundle. N.b., "local" refers (only) to the domain, as in "a locally-trivial fiber bundle." [1/2]

Briefly, then, the standard, widespread definition of meromorphic function on a Riemann surface $X$ is "a holomorphic map from $X$ to $\mathbf{CP}^{1}$" (possibly that is not identically equal to $\infty$). <> As I read it, you're asking, "Can we define a meromorphic mapping $f:X \to Y$ for an arbitrary Riemann surface $Y$?" If that's right, "Yes, we can, but the term is liable to mislead." Analogously, we could define a new type of `triangle' with seven sides, but that will contravene widespread expectations about the term triangle. [2/2]
